# Trying to run J/Link SampleProgram.java from Mac Terminal: Exception in thread "main"

Tags: export, import, warning-messages, mathlink-or-wstp, java

Trying to run the [WSTP J/Link SampleProgram.java][1] Mathematica version 11.0.1.0 file from the MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6 Terminal, generates "Exception in thread "main" ...

Updating to Oracle JDK 8u144 solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Mathematica installed in the default location, as /Applications/Mathematica.app, there is no need to adjust the command as given in the tutorial (the first one in your question).  If you have Mathematica installed in some different location or using some other name, you need to adjust the name leading up to the .app.  If you're not 100% sure where you are, using the "pwd" command to find the location.

Your problem is that your setting for -classpath is wrong, namely you are missing the .app between "Mathematica" and "/".  You can add the missing .app, or you can use the relative path suggest in the linked tutorial.

Comment: I used the "pwd" command, and location is /Part2 as indicated in terminal. Unadjusted command still returns the error.  Adjusted command as stated, with or without the .app, still returns the error. Must be still something else.

Comment: Mathematica was installed in the default location. Also added my system info above. The tutorial also says, "If you have your CLASSPATH environment variable set to include JLink.jar, then you can leave off the -classpath specification in these command lines." How might I set that, if it's something to try?

Comment: Tried to set CLASSPATH environment with "set CLASSPATH=JLink.jar" then: java  SampleProgram -linkmode launch -linkname '"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel" -mathlink' ...same Exception errors.

Comment: So, somewhere in the above screenshot, java command from directory holding .class and .java files is derailing the Wolfram Language kernel path from connecting /JLink.jar with .class .java returning: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, and I specifically tested on 10.12.6 to be sure.    What does 'java -version' return? My only guess is that perhaps you have an old version of Java installed.  You may need to contact support.

Comment: java -version returns:
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode) after updating yesterday

Comment: From a Linux thread, explanation of [Exception in thread "main"...]  "means that your class resides in the main package, and its canonical name is main.HelloWorld.

Java requires that package names should also be mirrored in the directory structure. This means that:

1. Your HelloWorld.java file should be in a directory named main
2. You should execute javac and java from the directory containing main, not from main itself" So in Part2 I mkdir main and cp SampleProgram.class and SampleProgram.java into Part2/main ...still same Exception.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that you are using an out of date java.  Does it work if you replace `java` in your command with `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/MacOSX-x86-64/bin/java`? When Apple deprecated Java, we had to switch to Oracle's java.  You can either use the local java in the layout, or globally install Java 8.  It's possible the documentation wasn't updated to make this clear.

Comment: Replacing java returns  /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/MacO‌​SX-x86-64/bin/java: No such file or directory. Documentation didn't discuss java, presently operating Oracle Java Version 8 Update 144

Comment: That sounds like you installation is damaged, or perhaps you have a very old version which still used Apple's java (but then I don't understand why the original command didn't work for you).  I suggest you contact support at this point.